# How to fetch data from 3rd party api and show it as wordpress post without importing to database?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

We have a WordPress website and an API endpoint that return posts from another system.
Now we want to show these posts in WordPress but without storing them in the database.

In general, we want WordPress to interact with these data like it is its own(but it isn't).

There is a solution by Andy in https://barn2.com/blog/create-fake-wordpress-post-fly/.

Is this the only way to do this or do you guys have something else in mind?

Comment: The question is somewhat unclear. Could you please clarify what is meant by "3rd party API"?

Are you trying to import or embed posts from a separate WordPress blog onto an existing WordPress website?